# Why are these routes conflicting?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have one Controller and two methods both with a different Route. .NET is complaining that the two routes are in conflict.

These are methods:

```
   [Route("portal/")]
    [HttpGet("{*slug}")]
    public IActionResult Portal(string slug)
    {
      var session = HttpContext.Get<LoggableEntities>(_context);
      ViewData["CurrentUser"] = session?.User;
      ViewData["CurrentAdmin"] = session?.Admin;

      ViewData["id"] = _context.Application.First().Id;
      ViewData["slug"] = slug;
      ViewData["Page"] = "Home/Index";
      ViewData["ProjectName"] = _projectNameOptions.Value;
      ViewData["app"] = "portal";
      return View();
    }


    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet("{*slug}")]
    public IActionResult PublicSite(string slug)
    {
      var session = HttpContext.Get<LoggableEntities>(_context);
      ViewData["CurrentUser"] = session?.User;
      ViewData["CurrentAdmin"] = session?.Admin;

      ViewData["id"] = _context.Application.First().Id;
      ViewData["slug"] = slug;
      ViewData["Page"] = "Home/Index";
      ViewData["ProjectName"] = _projectNameOptions.Value;
      ViewData["app"] = "public_site";
      return View();
    }
```

And this the error I get :

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied: MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.Portal (MyProject) MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.PublicSite (MyProject)

Comment: The problem was with the slug of portal needed to be `[HttpGet("portal/{*slug}")]` instead of `[HttpGet("{*slug}")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the [documentation of HttpGetAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httpgetattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The string parameter passed to the `HttpGet` attribute is the route template. So as you passed `{*slug}` yo your both `Action`s, they override the `Route` attribute and the conflict happens. So, You can remove the `[Route]` attribute and change your code to something like this:

```
[HttpGet("portal/{*slug}"), Order = 0]
// GET: portal/abc-def-123
public IActionResult Portal(string slug)
{
  var session = HttpContext.Get<LoggableEntities>(_context);
  ViewData["CurrentUser"] = session?.User;
  ViewData["CurrentAdmin"] = session?.Admin;

  ViewData["id"] = _context.Application.First().Id;
  ViewData["slug"] = slug;
  ViewData["Page"] = "Home/Index";
  ViewData["ProjectName"] = _projectNameOptions.Value;
  ViewData["app"] = "portal";
  return View();
}


[HttpGet("{*slug}", , Order = 1)]
public IActionResult PublicSite(string slug)
{
  var session = HttpContext.Get<LoggableEntities>(_context);
  ViewData["CurrentUser"] = session?.User;
  ViewData["CurrentAdmin"] = session?.Admin;

  ViewData["id"] = _context.Application.First().Id;
  ViewData["slug"] = slug;
  ViewData["Page"] = "Home/Index";
  ViewData["ProjectName"] = _projectNameOptions.Value;
  ViewData["app"] = "public_site";
  return View();
}
```

As the `{*slug}` route includes the `portal/{*slug}` route, The `Order` property makes sure that the former route checks before the latter one.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the route in the HttpGet property

like this

```
[HttpGet, Route("portal/")]
```